# Creating Symlinks from a iSCSI-Volume to a Fileserver

Tags: windows, backup, powershell, symbolic-link, iscsi

my fileserver is near capacity limit (using Windows 2012) und full of files, that hasn't been used for years, but still need to be kept for researches in the future. Furthermore the unused and unchanged data unnecessarily prolong the backup process.

Thats why i'm going to buy an archiveserver- with larger backup intervals and additional space. I've written a powershell script that is able, to detect and move files from a directroy to another depending on their "LastAccess"-attribute. The script would have been executed on the Fileserver.

After moving the files from the fileserver to the archiveserver i would like to create a symlink on the fileserver to the new storage location. So users can access to the data like before regardless they are stored on the fileserver or the archiveserver.

Should it work if i mount a iscsi-lun to the fileserver and just create sym-links?

if yes, will it be transparent for applications too or do they recognize the diffence between a "real" file and a softlink.

if no, do you got other suggestions that would solve my problem?

Comment: Can't you just test it with demo data? Or a copy of the data?

Comment: The problem is that i can't test every application of my 200 users... and before i order a new server i would like to know if my plans are realizable the way i think.